# Android - JNI crash on set Native C++ Variable

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have some JNI/C++ code that crashes when I try to set a variable in a C++ class.

```
void AndroidReflectionViewer::NativeSetVrActive(JNIEnv* env, jboolean active) {
    LOGW("This gets called fine");
    other_obj_.set_vr_enabled(active);
    LOGW("Code never gets to here");
}
```

In turn the `other_obj_` function looks like:

```
void set_vr_enabled(bool enabled) { 
    LOGW("Before bool set prints fine."); 
    what_eva = enabled;
    LOGW("After never prints"); 
}
```

It seems to crash when I set the `bool` in `other_obj_` to any value (or change any variable in that object really). Printing log statements is fine though. I've also tried `what_eva = true`, no difference.

```
? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x123e in tid 12243

          [ 01-19 09:18:54.062   457:  457 W/         ]
          debuggerd: handling request: pid=12243 uid=10143 gid=10143 tid=12243
I/nanohub: osLog: [BMI160] gyrPower: on=1, state=3
I/nanohub: osLog: [BMI160] magPower: on=1, state=4
? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:1870): avc: denied { search } for name="com.foo" dev="sda35" ino=877326 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:1871): avc: denied { search } for name="com.foo" dev="sda35" ino=877326 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

I read about the avc: denied errors on [Android source](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate.html). While those help to debug where the error come from, it doesn't give many suggestions as to what might actually be causing. So for the actual question:

**What could be causing this crash and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A couple of things seemed like they could be causing this problem:

- Maybe I wasn't in the right thread. I tried waiting for that thread
  and it didn't work.
- Maybe the jboolean was a problem? Converting and just setting
  `what_eva = true` didn't work.
- Maybe it's a race condition, where the Java code is
  being run before the C++ code is being initialized.

**The actual solution:**

The crash was caused by the race condition, where I tried to call C++ functions from Java before the C++ was initialized. I delayed a few  milliseconds before calling the C++ and it works. This doesn't seem super robust, but in this case I plan on calling it from a user activated button anyway. When I do that I shouldn't have to worry about the race condition.

Comment: I listed this as an answer since these are 3 possible solutions I got from coworkers to this problem. Only one of them actually worked, and I've separated that out firmly from the others here. But they all seem like plausible solutions someone else with a similar problem might be able to use.

Comment: This is a remarkably bad programming practice that is guaranteed to bite you in the future.